# compute slope of a 3D plane

Tags: c++, geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

I have a set of (X,Y,Z) points representing different planar features. I need to calculate the slope of each plane using normal vectors.
i think slope is given by the angle between normal vector (NV) of each plane and NV of imaginary horizontal plane. Assume, the plane equation that I use is; Ax+By+c=z. Then i guess the normal vector of my plane is (a,b, -1). For my plane equation, what should be the equation of imaginary horizontal plane? I think equation of horizontal plane is z=c. Hence, the normal vector is (0,0,-1). Is this correct?
Then the angle between my plane and the horizontal plane is;
cos^(-1)⁡〖(a.0+b.0+(-1).1)/(√(〖a1〗^2+〖b1〗^2+〖c1〗^2 ).√(0^2+0^2+1^2 ))〗

Is that correct? please comment me and give me the correct equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's mostly correct, but you've made some small mistakes substituting into the expression for the angle. The angle is cos^{-1} [(a * 0 + b * 0 + (-1) * (-1) / (√{a^2 + b^2 + (-1)^2} * √{0^2+0^2+(-1)^2}] = cos^{-1}(1/√{a^2 + b^2 + 1})

Comment: thanks for the reply. wish to clarify further few thing. how do i know my normal vector is going outward of the surface or inward. this inward, outward facing is relevant for both normal vectors. i know, + or - will come to the result. then, slope could be <90 or larger than that. So, please help me to get exact case.

Comment: There's no "outward" or "inward" (so far) in what you posted -- those terms only make sense if you're dealing with surfaces of bodies. If you want to calculate the slope of planar features without reference to any bodies, then by definition that's the positive angle between 0 and pi/2 (90°) that their normal vectors form with a vertical vector, and in my answer you automatically get such an angle because the cosine is always positive. Only the relative orientation of the two vectors matters; you can invert them both so they both have a z component of +1 and get the same dot product and cosine.