# Trying to calculate the slope of a plane from a normal

Tags: vector, angle, normals, plane

I have a set of 3D normal vectors for points on a 3D mesh, and I need to calculate the slope of the area below each of them. I have no idea how to do this. I don't need X or Y slope, I just need the total incline of the point in question (although to be fair, I don't know how to derive total slope from X and Y slope individually, which is part of my problem). I did see [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904922/compute-slope-of-a-3d-plane), but I couldn't really make heads or tails of it... The vectors are outward-facing. If anyone can explain this one to me, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have the normal vector, you're almost there. What you now need is the [angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle) (look for dot product) between the normal and a vertical line (what exactly *vertical* means depends on your application).

*If* your normal vectors are actually normalized (have length 1) and the vertical is (0 0 1), the cosine of the slope angle is simply the z coordinate of the normal vector.

To demonstrate this: Take a pen and let it stand on your table. This is your table's normal vector. The angle between this vector and a vertical line is zero, as your table has no slope at all. If you tilt your table by a certain amount, the angle between the normal and a vertical line will increase by the same amount.

Comment: My vectors are normalized. At least, they should be, assuming I didn't cock up the previous step (given my performance on this job so far, that's not a given either, but we'll roll with it). So in order to get the slope angle, all I need is something like this

Comment: `slope = math.cos(vector3.zCoordinate)`
?

Comment: no, the z coordinate _is_ the cosine, so you need to take the arccos of z

Comment: How could you apply this to get not the slope on Z axis but instead the x/y angle in compass degrees?